# How do I add value to a document that is expected to be created? (Firebase + React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to add a field (Username) to a firebase user's document, when i create it.

My logic :

1. Fill up form with email,pass & username field as well - WORKS.
2. Take the email & pass and sign up with firebase (createUserWithEmailAndPassword) - WORKS.
3. Right after the document creation (Hopefully) - fire an HTTP Firebase callable that will update userName field from the form - **FAILED**.

Error : Unhandled error { Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/yeu/databases/(default)/documents/users/DchYhQNMS12VYqzSwtEZ8UXYhcD3

I understand that there is no document (not yet) - so my question is how can i make sure that the document will be ready when it's need to be.

CODE:

> ReactJS - SignUp event, (using form & OnClick)

```
export function SignUp() {    

  const handleSignupSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const registerForm = document.querySelector(".register");

    // firebase
    const addUserName = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("addUserName");

    // register form
    const email = registerForm.email.value;
    const password = registerForm.password.value;
    const fullName = registerForm.fullName.value;

    // firebase sign up
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userAuth) => {
        console.log("registered", userAuth);
        addUserName({
          userName : fullName
        }).then(((doc)=>{
          console.log("UserName Added", doc);
        }))
        .catch((error) => {
          registerForm.reset();
          registerForm.querySelector(".error").textContent = error.message;
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        registerForm.querySelector(".error").textContent = error.message;
      });
  };
```

> Firebase Backend - Auth trigger

```
// auth trigger (new user signup)
exports.newUserSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // for background triggers you must return a value/promise
  return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
    userName: 'Temp',
    email: user.email,
  });
});
```

> Firebase Backend - HTTP Callable method

```
// http callable function (adding a username)
exports.addUserName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unauthenticated");
  }    
  const userRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(context.auth.uid);

  return userRef.get().then((doc) => {
    return userRef.update({
      userName: data.userName
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client app should wait for the document to become available before invoking the callable function.  The easiest way to do that is to [set up a realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) for the expected document, then call the function only after the listener gives you a callback indicating that the document is present and has data.

The pattern is described in more detail in [this blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07).  You should be able to copy what it's doing very closely.

Comment: Would you like to say more about that?